# Find a value within a div and replace

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 3 values that I need to replace within 3 divs.

```
<div class="bx-pager-item">
    <a class="bx-pager-link active" data-slide-index="0" href="">1</a>
</div>
<div class="bx-pager-item">
    <a class="bx-pager-link" data-slide-index="1" href="">2</a>
</div>
<div class="bx-pager-item">
    <a class="bx-pager-link" data-slide-index="2" href="">3</a>
</div>
```

I need to replace 1, with the value 'test'; 2 with the value 'test1'; and 3 with the value 'test2'.

I have tried the following code without any success, any help would be appreciated.:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    var fandreplace = document.getElementsByClassName('bx-pager-item').innerHTML.replace('3', 'test2'); 
});
```

Comment: Its a collection you need to loop through or use `[]` on the collection. and you need to assign to the innerHTML with modified html, since it is just a sstring rep and doesn't hold any reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to individually set them since the new html will be unique (you could do a loop depending on what you really want to replace it with).

Here's a simple way to change the inner html using the "index" of each element.

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vyPNU/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    $('.bx-pager-item:eq(0)').html('test'); 
    $('.bx-pager-item:eq(1)').html('test1'); 
    $('.bx-pager-item:eq(2)').html('test2'); 
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You should loop each element and replace their values accordingly.

**Replace based on Index**

```
$('.bx-pager-link').text(function (i, v) {
    return 'test' + (i > 0): (i - 1): '';
});
```

**Replace based on value**

```
$('.bx-pager-link').text(function (i, v) {
    var val = parseInt(v, 10);
    return 'test' + (val > 0): (val - 1): '';
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In jquery you would do

```
 $('.bx-pager-item > a').each(function(){
    var str = $(this).text().replace('3', 'test2');
    $(this).text(str);
});
```

and if you wanted several values

```
 var map = {'3':'test2', '1':'test'};
 $('.bx-pager-item > a').each(function(){
    $(this).text(map[$(this).text()]);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

### JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rNLvU/

```
$('.bx-pager-item').each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.text('test'+$this.text().trim());
});
```

note the text needs trimming in this instance as a leading space can occur in the element's text() value

Answer (score 0):

Try this : use each to select all the elements

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.bx-pager-link').each(function (i, elem) {
        $(elem).text('test '+i);
    });
});
```